# How to make constrained combinations of scenarios in NetLogo Behavior Space?

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

In my problem I have seven global variables to be controlled by Behavior Space.

Variable weights are in a range of 0 to 1 with an increment of 0.1 like,

```
[“A” [0 0.1 1]], 
[“B” [0 0.1 1]], 
[“C” [0 0.1 1]], 
[“D” [0 0.1 1]], 
[“E” [0 0.1 1]], 
[“F” [0 0.1 1]], 
[“G” [0 0.1 1]]
```

The restriction in my problem is that in each scenario the combination of all seven weights must be equal to “1” e,g;

```
0.2+0.2+0.2+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1=1
```

However Behavior Space, by default, makes all possible scenarios whether the sum of weights is equal to, greater than or lesser than “1”.

Can you please help me how to extract and use only those variable combinations in which the sum of weights is always equal to “1”.
Bundle of Thanks in anticipation.

I am a new NetLogo user without any programming background and in a desperate need of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stop condition in Behavior Space

[image: stop condition in BS]

like

```
A + B + C + D != 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. My concern in this case is totally with the output file for statistical analysis. Initially there are millions of total runs if all possible combinations are analyzed. I applied the mentioned stopping conditions but NetLogo still have to deal with that huge number of runs which it can't. I should tell NetLogo to consider only those combinations when sum is equal to one.  Can you please recommend any other solution? Your coordination is really appreciable.

Comment: you can use [openMole](http://www.openmole.org/current/) how can [deal with netlogo](http://www.openmole.org/current/documentation_console_task_netlogo.html) but it's another language...